# String to numpy array image

Tags: python, string, image, numpy, text

I want convert string to image.

What I want is :

input = string
output = 2D or 3D numpy array image consisting of 0, 255 maybe

Is there any package or module doing this??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use opencv2.putText

https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html

opencv-python workwith numpy.ndarray